# SharePoint workflows/Infopath

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a series of forms done in InfoPath.  What I need to do is when a form is complete, have a green "proceed" button show up at the bottom of the form, that then links the user to the next form in the phase/series.  If the person has not filled out the form, they should get a gray "not complete" button of some sort.

I am not sure if the best way to accomplish this is by using a workflow, and creating the forms in the workflow.  From there, I am not sure how to get the buttons to show, and the link to the next form to happen.

I am a beginning SharePoint developer with minimal coding experience but I understand workflows pretty well.  If there is a better way to accomplish this with forms that have already been created within Infopath - that would be great too.  We do already have the forms created, and basically want to link them with the buttons in between.

Hope this is clear enough.  Thanks for any advice/help you can give!  I am working in Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to jump from one form to another using form actions. 
InfoPath has a few rules that could be used to hide or show different buttons if a certain field or value meets a desired criteria.

Example: if a certain fields value equals "Your Value" then stop hiding the section or button. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2004/06/01/145557.aspx

For the redirection you could use a hyperlink that the user clicks on, but you probably need to ensure that the first form has been submitted. Or you could try and overwrite the source query string in the url. 
http://mysharepointexp.blogspot.se/2011/12/redirecting-infopath-form-after-submit.html